# How to convert horizontal row into vertical

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a Dynamic query  which fetch a row with 62 columns in sql

The query is like this

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max)

SELECT
  @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(Column_name)
FROM (SELECT
  Column_name
FROM
 (SELECT
  Column_name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column_name ORDER BY Column_name) AS Rows
FROM information_Schema.Columns

WHERE Table_Name IN ('Parking', 'AIV_Parking')
AND column_name NOT IN ('IssueNo', 'Issuedate', 'Agency', 'OfficerName', 'OfficerId', 'Beat', 'UNITSERIAL', 'VEHLICNO', 'VEHLICSTATE', 'VEHLICEXPDATE', 'VEHLICTYPE', 'VEHMAKE',
'VEHMODEL', 'VEHBODYSTYLE', 'VEHVIN4', 'VEHVIN', 'ISSUENOCHKDGT', 'VEHCOLOR1', 'VEHCOLOR2', 'PERMITNO', 'VEHLABELNO', 'LOCBLOCK', 'LOCSTREET', 'LOCDESCRIPTOR', 'LOCTRAVELDIR', 'LOCSIDEOFSTREET',
'LOCSUBURB', 'LOCLOT', 'LOCCROSSSTREET1', 'LOCCROSSSTREET2', 'LOCSTATE', 'LOCPOSTALCODE', 'METERNO', 'METERBAYNO', 'REMARK1', 'REMARK2')) p
WHERE Rows = 2) RequiredColumns

EXEC ('SELECT ' + @columns + '  FROM AIV_Parking Where  Issueno =''100000600''')
```

Which gives me below records

So result is Something like below  where i get only 1 row at a time.

```
|ACTLINE1  |    ACTLINE2 |   AUTOPROC_UNIQUEKEY |   COURTADDR|  IssueNo|.......

 |SUBIACO  |   LOCAL LAWS|       NULL            |      NULL |    123 |
```

Now i want this to converted like:

```
|FieldName       |                                    FieldValue

|ACTLINE1        |                                      SUBIACO  

|ACTLINE2        |                                      LOCAL LAWS 

|ISSUENO         |                                      123
```

While pivoting these column ,I want only those columns which has value i don't want those column whose value is null or ' '

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UNION ALL` and filter the result with a `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery +
'SELECT ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS FieldName, CAST(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)  + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FieldValue 
FROM AIV_Parking 
WHERE Issueno =''100000600'' 
UNION ALL' + CHAR(10)
--QUERY HERE TO GET COLUMNS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN('Parking','AIV_Parking')

IF @SQLQuery <> '' BEGIN
    -- Remove the last occurence of UNION ALL
    SELECT @SQLQuery = LEFT(@SQLQuery, LEN(@SQLQuery) - 11)

    SELECT @SQLQuery = 
    'SELECT * FROM (' + @SQLQuery + ') t WHERE FieldValue IS NOT NULL AND FieldValue <> '''''

    EXEC(@SQLQuery)
END
```

Note that you need to `CAST` your `FieldValue` to a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or whatever datatype that will not produce a conversion error. This is because when using `UNION` all columns must have the same datatype, if not, they will be converted to the one with the higher data type precedence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But it is not working,When I  insert the Query to  get columns ,it is not working

Comment: Let me see your query! Are you sure the query you're inserting is correct?

Comment: I am  using  your query But i think I am making some mistake .I am first trying  I get all the columns and it values in vertical format :SELECT 'ISSUENO' AS FieldName, CAST(QUOTENAME(ISSUENO) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FieldValue 
FROM AIV_Parking 
WHERE Issueno ='100000600' 
UNION ALL
Select Column_name,CAST(QUOTENAME(Column_name) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FieldValue  from information_Schema.Columns
Where Table_Name in ('Parking','AIV_Parking')

Comment: @Khushboo, you insert the wrong query. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @Khushboo, there. See my updated answer. You could run my entire answer directly.

Comment: Wow Thanku Soo much :)It was of great help

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)